# First time baker having issues with a normal map

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I just baked my first normal map (by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJ0PM7m9TJc) from Grant Abbitt). It's supposed to be a flat cable ribbon. I baked the normals from a higher poly mesh of some stitched-together cylinders. After applying the baked normal map to the low poly mesh, it looks decent in Cycles (ignore the sloppy texturing painting):

[image]

But it looks terrible in Eevee:

[image]

And, as soon as I deform the mesh in Cycles (like with a cloth sim), it immediately looks flat, like it does in Eeevee.

[image]

Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening? I'm pretty new to Blender and this is my first bake, so ELI5, if you don't mind :)

Cheers!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the scale of the low-poly object and it will work fine:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I thought I had already done that, but that explains a couple other hiccups I ran into... haha. Thanks!